# Change pureftpd mysql users default permissions

Tags: mysql, permissions, pureftpd

I would like to know how is it possible to change default permissions for MySQL Pureftpd users.
I want to do that because I would like that my users can access a directory that belong to an other unix user without having the permission to write in it. So the default owner and group of the MySQL user is the unix user, but is it possible to add permissions on this mysql-pureftpd user ?

I saw that we could set the default SID and GID for virtual users , can this solution work in my case ?

I tried with vuser and ACL but it didn't work.

Thanks for reading,have a good day